# AngularJs ng-if for displaying or skipping on element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using AngularJS.
I have the following template:

```
<div>
    ... html content ....
</div>
```

I want to  wrap the html content with an anchor **only if** the url model is not empty. For example, if `$scope.url = 'www.cnn.com'` then I want:

```
<div>
    <a ng-href="url"> 
        ... html content ....
    </a>
</div>
```

And if `$scope.url = ''` then I want:

```
<div>
    ... html content ....
</div>
```

Is there any way to do it in AngularJS?

Comment: your best bet is the switch statement since theres no ngElse unless you want to write two ngIfs one for true and one for false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I did it with a directive:

```
app.directive('skipElement', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var skip = attrs.skipElement ? !scope.$eval(attrs.skipElement) : false;
            if (skip) {
                var parent = element.parent();
                var children = element.children();

                children.detach();
                parent.append(children);
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: You shouldn't need a custom directive for simple basic functionality like this.

Comment: @olleicua: Dude, you didn't understand the question. If you'll show me  an example for what I am looking for in your way, I'll give you the V.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify the question because it says nothing about not wanting the duplicate the content.  What is this content anyway?

Comment: The content is html content.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ng-switch`:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

```
<div ng-switch="url.length">
<div ng-switch-when="0"> .. content .. </div>
<div ng-switch-default> <a ng-href="url"> .. content .. </a> </ANY>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to duplicate the content!

Comment: If you have a lot of content then you could use a template to abstract it away.  If it is relatively little content then you can use {{ content }}

Comment: What is {{ content }} ? How can it help me?

Comment: The first example on the front page of http://angularjs.org/ explains it pretty well.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: .. if you visit the angularjs home page the first example entitled "the basics" makes use of curly brackets to bind data from the model to the view.

Comment: I believe you didn't understand the question... {{ content }} is for bind models.

Comment: So what is this content then that you want inside your link?  If it's static and large enough to make duplication an issue then you can put it in a separate template to avoid duplication as I said in my first comment here.  I was assuming that your reason for wanting to avoid duplication was that the content was dynamic in which case why wouldn't it be in a model.

Comment: I didn't want for complicate the obvious. I already had a template and I didn't wanted to create another nested template. Although template was a fine answer, it wasn't the answer that you wrote. Anyway, I find the skipElement directive as a clear solution. Thanks for your help.